# Random ports open on VPS box

Tags: firewall, vps, port

I have a VPS box I just purchased.  It is running Apache and SSHD on their default ports.

When I do a port scan, I get results back that say port 139 and various other seemingly random ports are open.  I am not running any services that would use these ports.  The VPS provider provides console access over VNC.

iptables is running, and the rules are here:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state INVALID
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp echo-request state    NEW
OPEN-UDP   udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW
OPEN-TCP   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN state NEW
REJECT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with tcp-reset
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-proto-unreachable

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OPEN-TCP (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http

Chain OPEN-UDP (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:http
```

**EDIT:**

The result from James suggestion in comments (`netstat -anp | grep LISTEN | grep tcp`):

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

I have postgres running, but only accepting connections from localhost.

**Are these ports open because of the VNC software my VPS is providing (aka is this common?) or is it something I am doing wrong or have I been rooted?**

Comment: Hey can you run the following command and send back the results ` netstat -anp | grep LISTEN | grep tcp`

Comment: What distro are you using? Various distros have different default firewall confs.

Comment: @ajdecon, Arch Linux.  I had to configure iptables myself

Comment: @James, see my edit please

Comment: Eh, netstat does not list any VNC ports, 5900, I believe. If the IP number assigned to this box actually answers VNC, there seem to be some packet rewriting going on. In that case, perhaps port 139 is rewritten as well?

Comment: @Bittrance, vnc may be running on the supervisor rather than the host itself. This is virtual machine, after all. @vpn_noobe, could you post the output of your port scan ? Does it report ports that are open as tcp or udp ? UDP ports may be reported as "open" when the scanner does not get ICMP "port unrechable" in response to its probe packets. This does not mean ports are really open and is often the case when a firewall in front of the server silently drops packets.

Comment: Also, iptables rules look little strange, the very first rule in the INPUT chain accepts any packets so all other rules will never see any packets and do not matter. If this is the iptables configuration you run on this server, it should not block anything.

Answer (score 0):

Port 139 is a registered port for Windows file/printer sharing. Check to see if samba is running
`ps aux | grep smb`

Comment: Samba is not running or even installed